# Android Login Broken

Tags: android

I need help with making a login for my android app but when i put in the user it comes out with java.lang.NullPointerExption and its from the bottom part heres the ending code

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", un.getText().toString()));

        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pw.getText().toString()));

        //   String valid = "1";      

        String response = null;

        try {

           response =     CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://www.edgeblok.com/check.php", postParameters);

           String res = response.toString();

           //res = res.trim();

           res = res.replaceAll("\\s+","");

           // error.setText(res);

           if (res.equals("1")) error.setText("Correct Username or Password");

           else error.setText("Sorry!! Wrong Username or Password Entered");

        } 

        catch (Exception e) {

           error.setText(e.toString());

        }

     }


  });
}
```

}

Comment: Which line has the NullPointerException, it will be shown in logcat.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: `e.getStackTrace()`.  Also, it looks like error is never set before you use it in your code snippet.

Comment: can you create a chat from this please

Comment: You don't have to put it any where, just look at what it says there in the debugger and you'll see what line of code is causing the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Lets try, "Android People" I don't know if you can chat at all because of your low reputation.

Comment: i know whats doing it its the catch thing

Comment: We need to know why its failing not just that it is failing. The stacktrace will tell us where its failing which will lead us to why its failing. These are the questions we need answered: "What type is e?", "What line is e being thrown from?", and "How is variable `error` declared and defined?" Please put the answers to these questions in your original question by using the edit feature.

Comment: Type of variable, usually the system throws Exceptions of type `Exception` at last resort. More often its something specific like `IOException` or `InterruptedException` or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

Accoreding to comments (e in the catch clause is null), it seems as an Eclipse error I have met recently. Eclipse restart helps.

I see, we do not understand yet, where is the error an what it is. Put a breakpoint in the line `error.setText(e.toString());` and run the prog to it. Then look at e - is it null or nullpointexception? If e is null, look the first paragraph. If not, put the \breakpoint at the first line of the contemptuous code and after reaching it again, step the prog by code line by line (F6 in Eclipse) and find the line, which jumps to the error. After that put the breakpoint to that line, again restart and go to it. There check all objects - one of them will be null. Now, try to recall, why have you not made it something else :-)

Null could be your response or postParameters. They are the most probable pretendents.

Now, not checking your response for being null is a big and bad error, that you have to repair even if it is not the cause of your question error.

You are using some very rare class for connection. look [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android) for example

Comment: it shows the NullPointerExption in the text box on the device

Comment: the catch is what is making the text come up in the app text error is a text view

Comment: e.tostring is what makes the text

Comment: repair what? --- 'e.tostring is what makes the text' - it could make the text causing the second error or the text itself contains the words "nullpointerexception". Which one?

Comment: it the catch doing it but can i take it out

Comment: Excuse me, you are using other English language than I have studied.  Please, make you English sentences more understandable. Maybe, you write as you speak, but I am not from an English-speakin country and I do not understand you.

Comment: no, don't delete the catch. It is your only way to read and understand and then to find your error! Please, try to follow the algorithm that I wrote in my answer. It is the way as I look for errors, usually it helps.

Comment: When application stays on breakpoint, make doubleclick on the e, or stress it otherwards and nake rightclick. Choose "inspect". There will be a popup window with the value of e.